# Printing array In C

Tags: c

I am trying to input some values in arrays but cant print them out. Below is my code.please tell me what is wrong. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int win[99],tied[99],lost[99],streak[99],points[99];
    char name[] = "";

    for (i;i<=2;i++)
    {

        scanf("%s %d %d %d %d", &name[i] , &win[i] , &tied[i] , &lost[i] , &streak[i]);

        points[i] = win[i]*3 + tied[i];

    }
    for (i; i <= 2;i++){

        printf("%s \t%d \t%d\n", name[i], points[i] , streak[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (i; i <= 2;i++)` needs to be `for (i=0; i <= 2;i++)`. Otherwise `i` will already be `2` when the second `for` loop is reached. Also `&name[i]` is wrong as `name` only has one byte of memory.

Comment: You should read in an entire line with `fgets()`, and then parse it with `sscanf()`.

Comment: i did it like u said @kaylum but it now says file.exe stopped working when I execute it

Comment: What exactly did you do? It sounds like you fixed the first problem but not the second. Your declaration and/or use of `name` is wrong as there isn't enough/correct memory allocated. Which is likely to crash the program in the way you are observing. Try replacing `char name[] = "";` with `char name[3][99];`.

Comment: I got it thanks but what does char[3][99] do?

Comment: @NewProgrammer7 I'm not trying to be offensive but if you don't know what that does then you really should go back to review a basic C book/tutorial before proceeding with writing code. It declares a two dimensional array of chars.

Comment: i know its a 2D array but i just want to know why cant we declare name[3] or name[99] rather then array[3][99]

Comment: `name[3]` will only give you a buffer that can store 3 bytes. `name[99]` is better in that you can store 99 bytes. But what you really want are 3 buffers that can store 99 bytes each. Because the loop reads in 3 names. Hence `[3][99]`.

Comment: @NewProgrammer7, If you found an answer provided here helpful, please upvote and/or mark as accepted, so that other users with a similar question can benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Your second loop is not starting from 0, but starting from where the first left off, ie 2.
Reset it back to 0 and try again.